# Prism view containing own region throws exception on navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I tried to put a second region inside one of my existing Prism views.  Unfortunately, calling `RequestNavigate` with this region (and an externally-defined) view results in an `ArgumentException` that has the message.  "Region with the given name is already registered". I am trying to figure out how to make it work.

The Prism App (.NET 6, WPF, Prism 8.1) is a simple wizard with Next/Previous buttons.  The main window has a `ContentControl` as the main region. Very basic

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainWindow"
... blah blah blah...
>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Page" Grid.Row="1"
        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Main"/>

 ... wizard next/prev buttons, other stuff ...
```

The app registers several views/view-models that I can navigate to in that main region.  They are defined within the application assembly itself.
There is only one Prism view defined in another module.  This all works great.  I can navigate my main region to any of them with no problems.

```
RegionManager.RequestNavigate("Main", "WizardPage1"); // Defined in my app assembly
RegionManager.RequestNavigate("Main", "WizardPage2"); // Defined in my app assembly
RegionManager.RequestNavigate("Main", "ExternalView");  // Defined in another module.
```

The trouble came when I decided I wanted to use an internally-defined view to "host" the `ExternalView`.   So I created the new internal Prism view, `InternalHostView`, and I just gave it its own `ContentControl` with a different region name

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.InternalHostView"
... blah blah blah
>

    <ContentControl x:Name="SecondHost" 
        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="HostRegion"/>
```

When the user navigates to this new internal hosting view (in the  `InternalHostViewViewModel.OnNavigatedTo` function), I thought I could just take the region manager and navigate this "hosting" region to the external view.

public void  OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{

```
    // Navigate host region to the external Prism view
    // Note:  "RegionManager" obtained via constructor injection from Prism
    
    RegionManager.RequestNavigate("HostRegion",  "ExternalView");
}
```

Unfortunately This throws the aforementioned `ArgumentException`.

> Region with the given name is already registered: HostRegion

I cannot change the externally defined view.  It must remain external and it must remain a Prism view because it's used by another app.  It registers itself as my internal Prism views do, via `RegisterForNavigation`

Is there a way to do what I want?

Searching for this error message yields a number of people with the same problem.  But none of the solutions I've found (mainly trying to manually register the view myself) seem to help.

Comment: Could it be, that elsewhere a region "HostRegion" is defined? Have you tried to name your "HostRegion" as "MyHostRegion" instead?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  One of the early things I tried (I should have mentioned that I tried this in my question) was to rename the region from "HostRegion" to "MyHostRegion".  Unfortunately this had no effect.  I got the same error